# jquery load specific page / query strings

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following working code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#target').click(function() {
$("#success").load("/contacts/person/view/1", function(response, status, xhr) {
if (status == "error") {
var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
$("#error").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
}
});
});
});
</script>
```

I wish to have a series of links such as:

```
<a id="target">a</a>
<a id="target">b</a>
<a id="target">c</a>
```

Each of which should when clicked bring up a specific person. So each link will reference a particular person. Therefore depending on which link clicked the value of:

/contacts/person/view/**1**

must change.

How can I do this please?

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 2):

Consider placing the link for the AJAX request inside the A tag's href attribute, `<a href="/contacts/person/view/1" class="target">a</a>`.  Then you can use Rob W's code below with a slight modification:

```
<a href="/contacts/person/view/1" class="target">a</a>
<a href="/contacts/person/view/2" class="target">b</a>
<a href="/contacts/person/view/3" class="target">c</a>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.target').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#success").load(this.href, function(response, status, xhr) {
            if (status == "error") {
                var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
                $("#error").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Notice the difference is the URL parameter in load is set to `this.href`, `this` here refers to the `a` tag that was clicked on.

Comment: This is the best method, you should always include the href attribute of an anchor tag.

Comment: Also doesn't this need to include `preventDefault;` to stop the page going to the `href`?

Comment: @rickyduck is correct, it should preventDefault. I edited my answer to include it.

Answer (score 1):

You could assign a `data-id` to the `<a id="target" data-id="1">a</a>` and then assign the data-id value to a var in your function like so: `var personNumber = $(this).attr("data-id");`

Your Javascript would then look like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#target').live('click', function() {
        var personNumber = $(this).attr("data-id");
        $("#success").load("/contacts/person/view/"+personNumber, function(response, status, xhr) {
            if (status == "error") {
                var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
                $("#error").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

And your html would look like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="target" data-id="1">a</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="target" data-id="2">b</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="target" data-id="3">c</a>
```